# "Error [Joint.cc:408] Invalid joint index [2] when trying to apply force" with Gazebo 1.3

Tags: gazebo, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When spawning a URDF model using some custom controller plugins I get

```
Error [Joint.cc:408] Invalid joint index [2] when trying to apply force
```

spammed to the terminal when I spawn it using Gazebo 1.3 in Groovy (using .debs from the shadow-fixed repo). The controller plugins worked fine with fuerte before. Before I try delving deep into the differences between Gazebo plugin interfaces: Has anyone else encountered this and can provide some hints on where to look first?
The model otherwise appears to work (sensor data streaming for example).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1152/%22error-%5Bjoint.cc:408%5D-invalid-joint-index-%5B2%5D-when-trying-to-apply-force%22-with-gazebo-1.3/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 473 on 2013-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In older version of gazebo (1.0.x) that was in fuerte, `index` was ignored inside of [ODEHingeJoint::SetForce](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/13ac178834e050883f647b5dfb1e4ea926d1db76/gazebo/physics/ode/ODEHingeJoint.cc?at=fuerte#cl-144)):

```
void ODEHingeJoint::SetForce(int /*index*/, double _torque)
{
  if (this->childLink)
    this->childLink->SetEnabled(true);
  if (this->parentLink)
    this->parentLink->SetEnabled(true);
  dJointAddHingeTorque(this->jointId, _torque);
}
```

In latest groovy, [ODEHigneJoint::SetForce](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/5a51c98465a6ecf6da278d9b2e89e28dbe9fb85f/gazebo/physics/ode/ODEHingeJoint.cc?at=default#cl-143) was fixed to use the index correctly, thus exposing the bug you are seeing.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2